# Github Actions: How to include a file for github inputs?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following Github workflow:

```yaml
# workflow file
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      stage:
        type: choice
        description: Deployment stage
        options: # how to read the content for the options out of a file within the repo? 
        default: dev1
```

The file or the URL I want to retrieve contains the options of an input.

```yaml
# the content of the configuration file to include as 'options' in the workflow file
- Stage1
- Stage2
- StageN
```

What you can see in the comment of the workflow file, is the desired behavior.
I only saw the file-reader actions within the jobs/steps, but not for the meta data.

Comment: Could you be more specific, or give more context in the question please? What do you want exactly? To send a filename as input according to a list of options, and then read the file in the workflow to perform some operation? What kind of files are those?

Comment: Why not have a workflow for each option? Then user picks which workflow it needs. And to avoid any code duplication you can have reusable workflow that excepts `stage` as input.

Comment: @mchlfchr: The suggestion from @freenky is a good workaround, because it's currently not possible to achieve what you want natively using  a file to extract the `options` available for a workflow input.